# Sorting and filtering dataframes in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

That is my df

I want to sort the predictors_frame byt the Coef column, and filter by Pvalue < 0.05, but I am getting an error when I try to do it, i believe the syntax is incorrect. This is what I have so far.

```
predictors_frame = predictors_frame.sort_values(['Coef']), predictors_frame[predictors_frame['Pvalue']<.05]
```

The sorting is working properly but the filtering is what I have wrong. Is giving me the and AttributeEttor: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'head'

Comment: what you are doing is assigning two dataframes to one variable. in python that doesnt mean they gonna merge together magically.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ali":[4,5,3,4,5,8,7],"mali":[1,10,2,4,6,6,7]})

# output
   ali  mali
0   4   1
1   5   10
2   3   2
3   4   4
4   5   6
5   8   6
6   7   7

df[df.mali<5].sort_values(by="ali") # you could reset your index here also.

#output
   ali  mali
2   3   2
0   4   1
3   4   4
```

Comment: I have the following using your guidance and I still get the error of AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'Pvalue'

 predictors_frame = predictors_frame[predictors_frame.Pvalue < 0.05].sort_values(by='Coef')

Comment: predictors_frame = predictors_frame[predictors_frame.Pvalue < 0.05].sort_values(by='Coef')

Comment: @StackSuperLow try copying pasting your code in a good format and your dataframe in python to the question

Comment: `predictors_frame[predictors_frame["Pvalue"] < 0.05].sort_values(by='Coef')`

Comment: Nice yes now it worked I had a typo. Thank ombk!